# Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type WritableDraft<{}> | WritableDraft<User>

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to use redux toolkit with typescript in my application everything seems to be working fine until I got this error.
This is the code for my authSlice.
Am trying to create a user-dashboard via authentication but couldn't get past redux because the compiler kept yelling at me.

```
import { loadCurrentUser, CreateAccount, login, logout } from './auth.actions';
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { AuthState } from '../../../model/users-model';

let initialState = Object.freeze({
    isAuthenticated: false,
    error: '',
    status: 'idle',
    user: {},
}) as AuthState;

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        clearAuthError: (state) => {
            state.error = '';
        },
    },

    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(loadCurrentUser.pending, (state) => {
            state.status = 'pending';
        });

        //handles auth/loadCurrentUser
        builder.addCase(loadCurrentUser.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
            state.status = 'resolved';
            state.user = payload;
        });

        builder.addCase(loadCurrentUser.rejected, (state) => {
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            state.status = 'rejected';
        });

        builder.addCase(CreateAccount.pending, (state) => {
            state.status = 'pending';
        });

        builder.addCase(CreateAccount.fulfilled, (state, { payload}) => {
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
            state.status = 'resolved';
            state.user = payload;
        });

        builder.addCase(CreateAccount.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.error = payload as string;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            state.status = 'rejected';
        });

        builder.addCase(login.pending, (state) => {
            state.status = 'pending';
        });

        builder.addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
            state.status = 'resolved';
            state.user = payload;
        });

        builder.addCase(login.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.error = payload as string;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            state.status = 'rejected';
        });

        builder.addCase(logout.pending, (state) => {
            state.status = 'pending';
        });

        builder.addCase(logout.fulfilled, (state) => {
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            state.status = 'resolved';
            state.user = {};
        });

        builder.addCase(logout.rejected, (state) => {
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            state.status = 'rejected';
            state.user = {};
        });
    },
});

//actions from createSlice
export const { clearAuthError } = authSlice.actions;

//the reducer

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

and here is the code for my users-model

```
import { Action, ThunkAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { store } from '../reduxStore/app';

export enum ROLE {
    STUDENT = 'Student',
    TEACHER = 'Teacher',
}

export interface CreateAccountData {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    role: ROLE;
}
export interface User {
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
    email: string;
    avatar?: string;
    password: string;
    role?: ROLE;
    profile?: Profile;
}

// export interface UserResponse {
//  user: User;
//  token: string;
// }

export interface LoginData {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
export interface Profile {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    userId: string;
}

export interface CreateProfileData extends Omit<Profile, 'id' | 'userId'> {}

type Status = 'idle' | 'pending' | 'resolved' | 'rejected';
export interface AuthState {
    status: Status;
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    error: string;
    user: {} | User;
}

export interface ErrorState {
    message: string | null;
}

export interface ProfileState {
    status: Status;
    user: User;
    error: string;
}
```

Am new with typescript

Comment: You probably didn't paste the relevant code as `WritableDraft` does not appear anywhere

Comment: @Guerric thats whats is shown after it has compiled

Answer (score -2):

Try writing like this

```
builder.addCase(loadCurrentUser.fulfilled, (state, action: PayloadAction<{} | User>) => {
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
            state.status = 'resolved';
            state.user = payload;
        });
```

WritableDraft comes from redux toolkit, it's a way redux toolkit defines types